# Identify reason for NACK from I2C Slave

Tags: microcontroller, i2c

I am fairly new to I2C so please excuse my lack of knowledge. I am trying to read Data from an [PAC1710 sensor](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005386B.pdf) using an Stm32H743ZI MCU with the HAL-Library and the cubemx code generator.

I can send the first part of my message but I don't get an acknowledge after sending the address. I am using a 2700 Ohm resistor to ground on the ADDR_SEL Pin, ALERT goes to ground over an 10 kOhm resistor.

As for my code, this is my intializiation:

```c
void MX_I2C2_Init(void)
{
  hi2c2.Instance = I2C2;
  hi2c2.Init.Timing = 0x307075B1;
  hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c2.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c2.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c2.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c2.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c2.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c2) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Analogue filter */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c2, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Digital filter */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c2, 0) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

void HAL_I2C_MspInit(I2C_HandleTypeDef* i2cHandle)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if (i2cHandle->Instance == I2C2) {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C2_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C2_MspInit 0 */
  
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**I2C2 GPIO Configuration    
    PB11     ------> I2C2_SDA
    PF1     ------> I2C2_SCL 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOF, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* I2C2 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_I2C2_CLK_ENABLE();
  }
}
```

My implementation is very simplistic:

```sh
uint8_t i2cbuffer[8];
uint16_t val = 0;
HAL_StatusTypeDef ret;
```

and in the main loop I have the following code:

```sh
        i2cbuffer[0] = 254;
        ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c2, PAC1710Address << 1, i2cbuffer, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);   
        if (ret == HAL_OK) {
            ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c2, PAC1710Address << 1 , i2cbuffer, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
            if (ret == HAL_OK) {
                val = i2cbuffer[0];
            }
        }
        HAL_Delay(500);
```

I chose 254 because I though the slave should be able to answer to that regardless of his measurement. However I don't even get as far as sending the register, after looking into it with an oscilloscope I send the address and get a NACK.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Comment: You'll get a NAK if sensor is disconnected, not powered or not at that address. I think the write/transmit above should be to `(PAC1710Address << 1) + 1`. What exactly is in your oscilloscope trace (which bits, how fast, anything odd, does clock look ok?), and how is `ADDR_SEL` set on the sensor?

Comment: My sensor is powered and connected, the oszi shows 0x54 W ~a, so the address should be ok. The Oszi shows Start 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 Stopp.
As for the clock, there is a slight capacity influence but it looks ok.

Comment: 1010_100 does not match any of the addresses in sensor datasheet.

Comment: Isn't it adress(7 bit 101 0100), write(0), NACK?

Comment: I guess you can put space or _ wherever you wish, but that bit sequence does not appear in data sheet. There is the 0101_010, which you might have mixed it up with (this would mean that you shouldn't `<<1`)?

Comment: Thanks, that solved it for me ^^ 
Would you like to turn it into an answer? Than I could mark it.

Comment: What does it look like on the scope?  Note that I2C and SPI are not necessarily honored "standards" they are a bit loosy/goosy, so it could be that, but most likely you have the peripheral setup wrong and to see that just like uart and spi you need to get it on a scope, they are super cheap now (for these speeds).

Comment: You can try bit banging, and see if this is the peripheral setup address or something else.  When you swept the whole i2c address space how many i2c addresses hit and were any of them related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some comments, there was more useful info, biggest part being that oscilloscope showed `Start 1010100 0 1 Stop`. While `1010100` is the 0x54 address, the `W` bit needs to be counted as well, so the 8-bit data was actually `10101000`, instead of the expected `01010100`. Address should *not* have been shifted left, as it was already correct.

This is a somewhat common mistake with I2C. Attention needs to be paid to the exact address and `R/!W` bits, as in some documents and APIs they're shifted left, in some they aren't.

A very helpful bit of info here was the oscilloscope trace, that really helped show what exactly is going on.